# How to change Assembla Git committer picture

Tags: git, avatar, assembla

How to change committer picture on Assembla Git? Does it retrieve from Gravatar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commiter picture is profile picture of author of this commit, profile owner can edit own profile and (as part of it) load-change-remove avatar

No, Assembla avatars are local and not related (for now) with Gravatar

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that email used in git commits is the same as account email on assembla.com, otherwise commits will appear from Anonymous user.